# What are the accepted MIME content types for Google Cloud Storage (GCS)?

Tags: json, google-cloud-storage, mime-types, content-type

I have read the online documentation that I could find relating to uploading files to Google's Cloud Storage service (specifically the JSON api): 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload

And on that page it references another page/doc to "See the API reference for each method's list of accepted MIME types and size limits for uploaded files."
Which links to here:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/

With nothing I could find on the matter of MIME/content type.

Does anybody know what exactly is allowed to be set as content type on GCS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set any MIME type that conforms to the specification: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html